# How to take information from one webpage and link it to another in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I had an idea to create a chrome extension that would display the number of calories of ingredients in recipe websites online. I'm fairly new to developing extensions, and I have only done the basic ones of displaying text and changing words and images around on websites. My idea was to have the regular recipe but when you hover over the ingredients (or even just simply displayed on the website, whichever is easier) the caloric content would pop up. I'm wondering if it's possible to do that, because the inconsistencies with measurements and types of food can make it more difficult for a program to read. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is far too general. Show us an example explaining your problem.

Comment: The only possible answer to such question is yes, It's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this by below steps:

- Assume that there will be a parent DIV say `#DIV1Recipe` that holds the list `<LI>` of
  food and measurements say `#DIVFood1` and  `#DIVMeasure1`
- Loop through the each of the list item(`#DIVFoodX` and  `#DIVMeasureX`), find the food, get the
  measurement and calculate the calories of that one item
- Sum the total calories of all items in the same loop
- Inject this calories info to the parent div `#DIV1Recipe` as a new
  pop-up div `#DIV1RecipePopup`, and control its view by CSS `display` property onclick

For some inconsistent items, you may exclude them so that you can at least show the approximate calories of the recipe.

Also, you can make it even better by displaying a small form in the pop-up for missing measurements or unknown food, so that they can add or adjust the values and get the calories dynamically.  Maybe like this - https://simfatic.com/help/v40/images/popup-form.png

Hope it helps!